# Should I re-write all my ASP.NET web-services as WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Is there really an added benefit that worth the bother of spending time converting existing asmx web-services to WCF?

(I have about 10 web-services in the project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices.aspx), if you don't need "to guarantee message delivery, participate in transactions, or use binary serialization instead of XML," don't bother. ASMX still works fine for many purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If it's working and you don't have a specific requirement, then why change it?  Change as required, rather than just for the sake of it.